# stellar-core return error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: stellar-core

I installed stellar-core from stable repository. Stellar-core version 15.2.0. OS Ubuntu 18.04. I run command:

> stellar-core new-db --conf /etc/stellar/stellar-core.cfg

Stellar-core returned error:

```
2021-01-21T11:47:46.011 [default INFO] Config from /etc/stellar/stellar-core.cfg
2021-01-21T11:47:46.012 [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 3,
   "v" : [
      "sdf_watcher1",
      "sdf_watcher2",
      "sdf_watcher3",
      {
         "t" : 3,
         "v" : [ "stronghold1", "eno", "tempo.eu.com", "satoshipay" ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Config file i used this: https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/other/stellar-core-validator-example.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Please check the access rights when you run stellar-core (make sure you have proper access rights to the database and the `buckets` folder). We are tracking this issue in https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/2888, so feel free to add more details there if you still experience problems.